# Tinyxml to print attributes

Tags: c++, variables, string, constants, tinyxml

I'm trying to get std::string from attribute's value with TinyXml.
The only thing I can get is a const char * val, and I can't find any way to convert from const char * to a std::string.

so two possible answers to that:
1. How to get a string of an attribute with TinyXml?
2. How to convert **const char *** val to **string** val.

this is the code I have now:

```
TiXmlElement* data;
data->Attribute("some_name"); // return const char * which seems like unconvertible.
```

After googeling, I tried this:

```
char * not_const= const_cast<char *> (data->Attribute("some_name"));
```

There are no errors in the code itself, but after compiling and running I get exceptions.

Comment: TinyXML is not a very good XML library. I would recommend LibXML++ instead, since you are using C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::string has a constructor that takes char const*. You don't need a char* for that.

```
std::string str = data->Attribute("some_name");
```

However, be aware that std::string doesn't like NULL values, so don't give it any.

Comment: can't believe i spent more than a hour on this shit.
Thanks a lot!